# Implementing HTTPs proxy server with Netty

Tags: http, https, proxy, netty

I'm now implementing proxy server with Netty.
My proxy can send http data from client to server and vice versa.
But when I tried to access https sites, the data from client to server with curl shows 1401E10B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:wrong version number error.
[Error message figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaQaS.png)

What I've done so far is followings.

1. Make a pipeline for http

Client to Proxy pipeline

> HttpServerCodec -> HttpObjectAggregator -> ClientToProxyHandler

in ClientToProxyHandler, my proxy server makes TCP connect to remote server

Proxy to remove server pipeline

> HttpClientCodec -> HttpObjectAggregator -> ProxyToServerHandler

in ProxyToServerHandler, just send the responses from remote server to inboundChannel.

with these pipeline, http requests work well.

2. To send encrypted messages from client to remote server, when proxy receive https initial request, proxy make tcp connection to remote server and send 200 Connection established to client. Also,in that time, I removed HttpCodecs and HttpObjectAggregator from pipeline because I think encrypted data does not need HttpCodecs and HttpObjectAggregator.

with these structure, the result shows TLS handshake failure like figure above.

Also, I think this is not a version problem in curl because when I run LittleProxy and entered same curl command, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you have an `SslHandler` in the pipeline, you need to add that for `https` traffic.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I think sslHandler is not required, because I checked similar examples like LittleProxy[link](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy).
There don't use sslhandler when they just proceed https request without any options like mitm proxy, self-signed certificate and it works.